# when a user reject the geolocation service, do i get the reject event?

Tags: geolocation

I mean, if i have a button on the web page, when a user click the button,

then can get the user's geolocation information.

but before, the browser will ask the user whether accept to use the geolocation service.

if the user reject the geolocation service, can i get the reject event?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(){
    alert('Thanks for allowing geolocation!');
}

function errorCallback(){
    alert('You denied us access to geolocation...');
}
```

Check [Geolocation API Specificatio](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)n for further reference.

Comment: The errorCallback does not get called if the user decides to close the pop up without sharing his location, though.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't get called in Firefox (unless you choose 'never share').  It does in Chrome though.  Inconvenient.