# Geolocation without permission in manifest

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, geolocation, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use geolocation API in chrome extension without including the "geolocation" permission in manifest.json?

Like can we ask permission through the background.html file which runs the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in a content script without declaring a permission.

This would trigger a standard notification bar asking if you want to allow current site (not your extension) to access geolocation. If user allows it, you can then pass received geolocation position to a background page for further processing.

This approach might work if your extension is injecting a content script to a single domain, otherwise user would have to allow geolocation for each domain they visit.

The code should look like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log("Latitude : "+position.coords.latitude+":"+"Longitude : "+ position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Comment: could you help me figure out how it could be done through a content script ?

Comment: @user782400 Content script would allow you to use geolocation only when a user visits sites where your content scripts were injected. This approach would work for an extension that works only on youtube .com for example, but it wouldn't work for extension that has a browser popup or running in background on all sites.

Comment: So as far as I understand, the websites will be in the manifest.json file and then what will the content_script return as data ?

Comment: @user782400 Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. Content scripts don't "return" anything, it is just a javascript code that is getting injected to a parent site. They can communicate with a background page though, so when you run code that retrieves user's current position in a content scripts, you can then sent this position to a background page. If you are not familiar with content scripts then read this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html

Comment: sorry for the complicated question. However, I tried what you said and while injecting the script into a url; I get an "unknown error".

Comment: if(window.navigator.geolocation)
        success();

    function success(position){
        console.log("Latitude : "+position.coords.latitude+":"+Longitude : "+ position.coords.longitude);

Comment: sorry for the disorganization. I dont know how to put it in a formatted way.

Comment: so, when I click allow/deny; is there any value returned. For example : 0 if allowed and -1 if permission denied ?

Comment: @user782400 That function that takes position as a parameter just wouldn't run I suppose. Just look at geolocation API, it's not Chrome related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512619/when-a-user-reject-the-geolocation-service-do-i-get-the-reject-event

Comment: Boy. SO comment system sucks. @user782400 take a look at this SO question. You can check for success or rejection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512619/when-a-user-reject-the-geolocation-service-do-i-get-the-reject-event

Comment: hat that means is, once the permission is denied; it wont even give the location if we use getCurrentPosition inside the errorCallback function when the error code is 1 ???

i.e.
function errorCallback(e){
if(e.code ==1)
{   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()....}
}
would this still work  ?

Comment: now everything works, except that it does not logs the coordinates to the console even though I have console.log. It shows an error saying "chrome/ExtensionProcessBindings:95 Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error."
However, when asked to alert; it alerts the right coordinates.

Comment: @user782400 Please create another question and provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Nope:</s>

"An array of permissions that the extension or app might use. Each permission can be either one of a list of known strings (such as "geolocation") or a match pattern that gives access to one or more hosts. Permissions can help to limit damage if your extension or app is attacked."

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

...and here:

Your physical location   "geolocation" permission   Allows the extension to use the proposed HTML5 geolocation API without prompting the user for permission.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html

Actually, after looking at it a bit more you can but the user will be prompted for permission:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/

...and this page from Google says you can use this API and others:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_other.html